# Log Date a Loop Ends To Variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

Rails 3 Ruby 2.9 E-commerce app

I have a "expired" method whose value can be 1 or 0.

I want to be able to log when the "expired" method reaches 0 to a separate variable. I think it would be something similar to the code below but i am not sure how to capture the time the loop was broken.

```
 def date_expired
   for  units_available (product) in 0..1
   if  units_available (product) == 0 then
    break
  end
 date_expired == (time loop was broken)
 end
```

Comment: https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Answer (score -1):

If you think that this method of your will work fine according to your logic(because you have mot provided much details) then

```
 def date_expired
   for  units_available (product) in 0..1
   if  units_available (product) == 0 then
     current_time = Time.now
     break
   end
   return current_time
 end
```

In another but more efficient way you can just do

```
 def date_expired
   for  units_available (product) in 0..1
   if  units_available (product) == 0 then
     return Time.now
   end       
 end
```